# Simplify an expression in Mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions

```
    (Sqrt[t2] Sqrt[t1 t2] z12 + Sqrt[t3] Sqrt[t1 t3] z13)^3/(Sqrt[t1 t2] Sqrt[t2 t3] z12 z23 (Sqrt[t1] Sqrt[t1 t3] z13 + Sqrt[t2] Sqrt[t2 t3] z23) (-2 t1  t2 z12 z12bar -  2 t1 t3 z13 z13bar - 2 t2 t3 z23 z23bar))
```

I want to simplify the above expression in Mathematica.
Firstly, I use **Simplify**, but nothing happens.
Then, I use **Refine**, and the result becomes better but not completely solved.

```
    Refine[(Sqrt[t2] Sqrt[t1 t2] z12 + Sqrt[t3] Sqrt[t1 t3] z13)^3/(Sqrt[t1 t2] Sqrt[t2 t3] z12 z23 (Sqrt[t1] Sqrt[t1 t3] z13 + Sqrt[t2] Sqrt[t2 t3] z23) (-2 t1 t2 z12 z12bar - 2 t1 t3 z13 z13bar - 2 t2 t3 z23 z23bar)), {t1 > 0, t2 > 0, t3 > 0}] // Simplify
```

the result is

```
   -((t1^(5/2) Sqrt[t3] (t2 z12 + t3 z13)^3)/(2 t2 (t1 t3)^(3/2) z12 z23 (t1 z13 + t2 z23) (t1 t2 z12 z12bar + t1 t3 z13 z13bar + t2 t3 z23 z23bar)))
```

t1 and t3 between numerator and denominator aren't reduced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reduce `t1,t3` too you need additional restrictions `t1!=0, t3!=0`!

```
expr=   (Sqrt[t2] Sqrt[t1 t2] z12 + Sqrt[t3] Sqrt[t1 t3] z13)^3/(Sqrt[t1 t2]Sqrt[t2 t3] z12 z23 (Sqrt[t1] Sqrt[t1 t3] z13 + Sqrt[t2] Sqrt[t2 t3] z23) (-2t1  t2 z12 z12bar -  2 t1 t3 z13 z13bar - 2 t2 t3 z23 z23bar));

Simplify[expr,{t1>0,t3>0}]
(*(t1 (t2 z12 + t3 z13)^3)/(2 t2 t3 z12 z23 (t1 z13 +t2 z23) (t1 t2 z12 z12bar + t1 t3 z13 z13bar + t2 t3 z23 z23bar))*)
```

Comment: yes, adding the additional restrictions t1!=0, t3!=0 can get the correctly answer. but t1>0 and t3>0 have contained t1!=0, t3!=0. why still need them?

Comment: Because `division by zero` usually is problematic in math